# How to use appcmd to set debug=false in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, appcmd

I'm trying to use `APPCMD` to set `debug=false` in `web.config`, per the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725812(WS.10).aspx).

The specific syntax I am using is:

> `APPCMD SET CONFIG "SITE/VDIR" section:compilation /debug:False /commit:APP`

the output is

`INFO ( section:compilation, timetaken:219, hresult:00000000, objects:1 )
Applied configuration changes to section "system.web/compilation" for "MACHINE/W
EBROOT/APPHOST/SITE/VDIR" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WE
BROOT/APPHOST/SITE/VDIR"`

Afterwards, `debug` still is set to `true`.

I have ruled out the file being read only; I have used process monitor to watch appcmd actually write to web.config in the correct location.  My environment is Windows 2008 x64, SP2.

I understand that there are many different ways to solve the problem; different config files, doing it myself in xpath, nant, etc, but I'm specifically interested in why `APPCMD` does not seem to be working, and to help others who may also be struggling with the tool. Thanks for your help!

Comment: John - this has been confirmed as an issue by a MS employee, he's written up a workaround which may not be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug or 'by design'. Having investigated this I noticed that it's possible to add and modify other attributes of the `<compilation />` section (I haven't tried them all).

For example the following work just fine:

> `APPCMD SET CONFIG "SITE/VDIR" section:compilation /batch:False /commit:APP`
>   `APPCMD SET CONFIG "SITE/VDIR" section:compilation /defaultLanguage:"c#" /commit:APP`

But as you observe it's just not possible to alter the `debug` attribute. It may be worth raising this as a bug on the MS Connect site if you've got that ability:

> [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/)

I also popped a question on the IIS forums:

> [Possible bug: Unable to set the "debug" attribute in the "compilation" section in web.config (IIS.NET)](http://forums.iis.net/p/1162636/1924758.aspx)

**Update:**

This has been confirmed as an issue by a Microsoft employee:

> [Reply to Possible bug: Unable to set the "debug" attribute in the "compilation" section in web.config (IIS.NET)](http://forums.iis.net/p/1162636/1925544.aspx#1925544)

Comment: While this may have been correct in 2009, @Renato's answer below, 2019, is correct. You need to use `!` as an escape character. It works great.

Answer (score 1):

By [Catherine Shan's answer](https://forums.iis.net/p/1162636/1925544.aspx#2043323), "/debug" is a special switch for AppCmd.exe and needs to be escaped as"/!debug".

For example:

```
APPCMD SET CONFIG "SITE/VDIR" section:compilation /!debug:False /commit:APP
```

The answer post is February 21st, 2013, but it helped me today, better late than never.

Comment: Confirmed 04/21/23.